# A definition for sheaves on stacks

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory, topos-theory, stable-homotopy-theory

Here's is a definition of sheaves on stacks in the famous *Complex Oriented Cohomology Theories and the Language of Stacks* (COCTALOS) lecture notes by Mike Hopkins. Since it was written by students and wasn't entirely polished, it is at times a little hard (for me) to comprehend. Here is a definition that doesn't make sense to me.

**Definition** [COCTALOS, Def. 11.1]**.** Let $(\mathscr{C}, J)$ be a site, $\mathbf{Stack}$ be the $2$-category of stacks on $(\mathscr{C}, J)$ and $\mathcal{M} \in \mathbf{Stack}$. Then, we define $$\mathbf{Sh}(\mathcal{M}) = \mathbf{Sh}(\mathbf{Stack}_{/\mathcal{M}}),$$
i.e. a sheaf on $\mathcal{M}$ is a functor $(\mathbf{Stack}_{\mathcal{M}})^{\mathrm{op}} \to \mathbf{Set}$ (or to $(\mathbf{Stack}_{\mathcal{M}})^{\mathrm{op}} \to \mathbf{An}$ if you like) satisfying the sheaf condition.

But what is the Grothendieck topology on $\mathbf{Stack}_{/\mathcal{M}}$? Don't we need a site to be able to take sheaves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the Grothendieck topology meant here is defined in Example 8.25 in those lecture notes, as Proposition 9.2 tells you this is in fact a Grothendieck topology. (Also, it leads to a reasonable notion of a sheaf on a stack, since we are passing from sheaves on objects in $\mathscr{C}$ to sheaves on a stack by using representable morphisms.)

Comment: Oh that makes sense, I don‘t know how I forgot about that example. Thanks, Daniël!

Comment: Of course, always happy to help you!